# How can I make a select count(*) with where clause from another table return empty rows?

Tags: postgresql

I'm stuck with this problem:

I have 2 tables:

tbl_statistics:

```
id   |   name
1    |  Clicks on purchase button
2    |  Total logins
```

tbl_statistics_detailed:

```
id   |  stat_id (FK) |  date
1    |      2        | 2019-05-10 18:30:00
```

When i do the following command on postgre:

```
SELECT s.name, count(sd.id) AS count 
FROM tbl_statistics_detailed sd 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_statistics s ON s.id = sd.stat_id 
WHERE sd.date BETWEEN '2019-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-21 00:00:00'
GROUP BY sd.stat_id,s.name;
```

the result I get is:

```
name          |  count
Total logins  |    1
```

But what i want is:

```
name                          |  count
Total logins                  |    1
Clicks on the purchase button |    0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to further improve understanding of the matter, when I remove the where clause from this query, it gets the result I expect, but I need the results between dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `sd.date` is null for details not present and therefore your `WHERE` clause cannot be true for them Shift that into the join condition. And while you're at it, probably make it a left join. That's easier to read.

```
SELECT s.name,
       count(sd.id) count 
       FROM tbl_statistics s
            LEFT JOIN tbl_statistics_detailed sd 
                      ON sd.stat_id = s.id
                         AND sd.date BETWEEN '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
                                             AND '2019-05-21 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY s.name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly! But aside from readability, is there any difference in making a left join instead of a right?

Comment: @MugiGust: Welcome! And yes, the side the table that is in the result in any case has to be on is different obviously. But other than that no.

Comment: Yeah, moving the where condition into the join condition is better than OR-ing it with `is null`

Answer (score 0):

your right outer join is creating the following rows before filtering / grouping by:

```
sd.id | sd.stat_id | sd.date |    s.id   |   s.name
 NULL |  NULL      |  NULL   |    1      |  Clicks on purchase button
  1   |     2      | 5/10    |    2      |  Total logins
```

which is what you want, but then your `WHERE` clause is filtering out that first row.  could check that date is between your desired range `OR date is null` instead and it should give you what you want, since you're doing a `count(sd.id)` which should ignore the NULL values.